# removeChild() Function should only remove appendChild() Function Entries in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I Created a HTML Table and Created 1 Row in it... I created two functions first to Clone and the Row and second to Remove the Row..

using appendchild and removechild function

But removeChild Function Deletes the Main Row as well...

I want the removeChild Function to be only able to remove cloned Rows, Not the original row...
Note: in Clone of Row, I have replaced the ID with " ". to remove duplicate id.

i Tried to do this by creating a if statement which check if the id of row is same as original row only then remove the row. but I think I am not doing it in right way.. Below is code..

```
<table id="table-logic">
    <tbody id="qualiBody">
        <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<a onclick="cloneRow()">Add Row</a><br> 
<a onclick="removeRow()">Remove Row</a>


//clone Row with changed id
function cloneRow() {
    var row = document.getElementById('addr00'); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById("qualiBody"); // find table body to append to
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    clone.id = ' '; // change id to a blank space
    table.appendChild(clone) // add new row to end of table

}

//Remove Row
function removeRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("qualiBody"); // find table to append to

    var mainRow = document.getElementById("qualiBody")
    if (mainRow.childNodes.id != 'addr00') {
        table.removeChild(qualiBody.lastChild);
    }
}
```

I expect to make my removeRow Function only remove cloned Rows... Not the Original Row...

I think the if statement can work in that part by Just making javascript check the id of element... if id of row != id of original row .. remove last child.

Comment: You want to remove all cloned rows or only one ? First of all the `mainRow.childNodes` have no id (Is an array). Is 'undefined' and is true all the time.

Comment: I want to remove them one by one... Currently, it is doing the same but It is also removing the original row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//clone Row with changed id
function cloneRow() {
    var row = document.getElementById('addr00'); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById("qualiBody"); // find table body to append to
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    clone.classList.add("cloned");
    table.appendChild(clone) // add new row to end of table

}

//Remove Row
function removeRow()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("qualiBody");
    let last = table.lastElementChild;
    
    if (last.classList.contains("cloned"))
    {
        last.remove();
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="table-logic">
    <tbody id="qualiBody">
        <tr id="addr00"><td>column 1</td><td>column 2</td><td>column 3</td><td>column 4</td></tr>
        <tr class="cloned"><td>column 1</td><td>column 2</td><td>column 3</td><td>column 4</td></tr>
        <tr class="cloned"><td>column 1</td><td>column 2</td><td>column 3</td><td>column 4</td></tr>
        <tr class="cloned"><td>column 1</td><td>column 2</td><td>column 3</td><td>column 4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<a onclick="cloneRow()">Add Row</a><br> 
<a onclick="removeRow()">Remove Row</a>
```

Comment: Thanks You Solved My Problem but there is problem in this code.. When You add 4 rows or more... the Remove Function Removes Multiple Rows.... incase of 4 rows it removes 2 rows and if more rows are added .. remove function then removes 3 and this increasing as more rows are added... a little bug...is here

Comment: I understand wat uou want in the previous comment. Let me edit.